# foreach loop and reference of &$value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Why is an empty foreach loop can change the result.

I have the following code:

```
$variable = [1,2,3,4];
foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) 
  $value ++;

var_dump($variable);
```

The result I get is:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 4
  3 => &int 5
```

Now, when I add an empty foreach loop like this:

```
$variable  = [1,2,3,4];
foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) 
  $value ++;

foreach ($variable  as $key => $value);

var_dump($variable);
```

I get this :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 4
  3 => &int 4
```

can someone explain me why the last element doesn't change when I add the second empty loop, and why there is a & infront of the last element?

Comment: +1 That's a funky issue you have there, interested in the explanation as-well.

Comment: The second loop seems to be causing the issue no matter what. Even if I do something useful in there, it alters the result. I'll look into it.

Comment: As [mentioned in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), you should `unset()` references after use ~ *"**Warning**
Reference of a `$value` and the last array element remain even after the `foreach` loop. It is recommended to destroy it by `unset()`."*

Comment: @Phil yes , I know , but I just need logical explaination

Comment: @Khalid Going into the second loop, `$value` is still a reference to the last item in the list. Think about that

Comment: `unset()` seems to be the solution, but doesn't explain why the second (empty) foreach loop _alters_ the values. It is still set as a reference, that's known. But how is it being altered? That's the question of the OP.

Comment: nice question. bookmarked

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the end of the first loop, `$value` is pointing to the same place as `$variable[3]` (**they are pointing to the same location in memory**):

```
$variable  = [1,2,3,4];
foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) 
    $value ++;
```

Even as this loop is finished, `$value` is still a reference that's pointing to the same location in memory as `$variable[3]`, so each time you store a value in `$value`, this also overwrites the value stored for `$variable[3]`:

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value);
var_dump($variable);
```

With each evaluation of this foreach, both `$value` and `$variable[3]` are becoming equal to the value of the iterable item in $variable.

So in the 3rd iteration of the second loop, `$value` and `$variable[3]` become equal to 4 by reference, then during the 4th and final iteration of the second loop, nothing changes because you're passing the value of `$variable[3]` (which is still `&$value`) to `$value` (which is still `&$value`).

It's very confusing, but it's not even slightly idiosyncratic; it's the code executing *exactly* as it should.

More info here: [PHP: Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

---

To prevent this behavior it is sufficient to add an `unset($value);` statement after each loop where it is used. An alternative to the `unset` may be to enclose the `foreach` loop in a self calling closure, in order to force `$value` to be local, but the amount of additional characters needed to do that is bigger than just unsetting it:

```php
(function($variable){
   foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) $value++;
})($variable);
```

Comment: Isn't this a language defect? The $value variable should be local for the foreach loop and not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 13):

This is a name collision: the name $value introduced in the first loop exists after it and is used in the second loop. So all assignments to it are in fact assignments to the original array. What you did is easier observed in this code:

```
  $variable = [1,2,3,4];
  foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) 
    $value ++;
  $value = 123; // <= here you alter the array!
  var_dump($variable);
```

and you will see `$variable[3]` as `123`.

One way to avoid this is, as others said, to `unset ($value)` after the loop, which should be a good practice as recommended by the manual. Another way is to use another variable in the second loop:

```
  $variable  = [1,2,3,4];
  foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) 
    $value ++;
  foreach ($variable  as $key => $val);
  var_dump($variable);
```

which does not alter your array.

Comment: I wish PHP and Python had a way to declare new variables -- that is, just indicate that I expect this variable to be new, as in Perl (`my`), Java (`var`), or LaTeX (`\newcommand`). Tiny extra effort, HUGE benefit in debugging time and in losses because of incorrect programs.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh I've always thought that myself! Luckily when PHP is written well these issues are minimized by data encapsulation and scope, but unluckily PHP is often not written well...

Comment: @chjohasbrouck A partial solution would be to write a function `new()` which dies if the variable is `isset`, and use it systematically. It would prevent a situation described in this question. But this does not prevent from typos: `$variable = 1; $varuable++; echo $variable;`, which prints `1` with no warning. Very stupid of the creators of such languages.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh here the problem may not only be with a variable with the same name, as well as when copying an array. the array contains a link and a copy of the array will modify the original array.

Answer (score 5):

The last element of the array will remian even after the foreach loop ..So its needed to use `unset` function outside the loop ..That is

```
$variable  = [1,2,3,4];
  foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) {
$value++;


}
  unset($value);
  var_dump($variable);
```

The link to the manual can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 4):

[As `phil` stated in the comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902742/foreach-loop-and-reference-of-value#comment38687419_24902742)

> As mentioned in the manual, you should unset() references after use.

---

```
$variable  = [1,2,3,4];

foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value)  {
  $value ++;
}
unset($value);

foreach ($variable  as $key => $value);


print_r($variable);
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/170837)

---

**Explanation**

Taken from the [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) manual. (<sup>*See the big red box*</sup>)

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the
>   foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

It basically means: That the referenced value `&$value` and the last element/item in the array, which in this case is `4` remain the same. To counter-act this issue, you'll have to `unset()` the value after use, otherwise it will stay in the array as its original value (*if that makes sense*).

You should also read this: [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works?rq=1)

Comment: Might as well just unset it *after* the loop

Comment: That unset should be outside the loop

Comment: yes, you are right, but can you give me explaination, why a foreach loop can cause this problem

Comment: @Phil & Hanky - sorry took it from the eval.in where I was testing!

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Don't really see a problem using it inside the loop, unless you're in to micro-optimisation

Comment: @Darren sorry, but I still don't get it ... after the fisrt loop, the value of `$value` is `5` (I just tested) the second loop, doesn't do anything, obviously the last value should be  `5` too, how come it is 4

Answer (score 4):

After loop you should unset this reference using:

```
unset($value);
```

So your whole code should work like this:

```
  $variable  = [1,2,3,4];
  foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) {
    $value++;
  }
  unset($value);
  var_dump($variable);
```

There is no point to put `unset($value);` inside the loop

Explanation - after loop $value is still set to the last element of array so you can use after your loop `$value = 10;` (before unset) and you will see that last element of array has been changed to `10`. It seems that `var_dump` want to help us a bit in this case and shows there is reference for last element and of course when we use `unset` we have desired output of `var_dump`.

You could also look at the following script:

```
<?php
  $array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  var_dump($array);

  $x = &$array[2];

  var_dump($array);

  $x += 20;

  unset($x);

  var_dump($array);

?>
```

We don't use loop here and if reference is set to element of array, `var_dump` shows us this putting `&` before type of this element.

However if the above code we changed reference and set it this way `$x = &$array;` var_dump wouldn't show us any reference.

Also in the following code:

```
<?php
$x = 23;
$ref = &$x;

var_dump($x);

?>
```

`var_dump()` won't give us any hint.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky it's because we are not looking for the solution, we are looking for explaination

Comment: @Khalid I've added explanation

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek your right about assaigning a value after the first loop, the last element change, I understand why the last element of the array is a reference ... but how come the second loop makes the last element like the one before ?

Comment: @Khalid I don't see any reason to think about it. Simply the code is wrong because you don't unset reference after first loop. There is no point for me to think why it works this way

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek It helps some to know why they're supposed to follow a particular advice :)

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory statement: References are evil!

Stepping through your code:

```
$variable  = [1,2,3,4];
foreach ($variable  as $key => &$value) 
    $value++;
```

After the loop completes; `$value` is a reference to `$variable[3]` and thus has the value of `int(4)`.

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value);
```

At each iteration, `$variable[3]` gets assigned an element of `$variable[<k>]` where `0 <= k < 3`. At the last iteration it gets assigned to its own value which is that of the previous iteration, so it's `int(4)`.

Unsetting `$value` in between the two loops resolves the situation. See also [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462394/last-item-in-foreach-loop-is-the-array-it-is-traversing) by me.

Comment: @Khalid it's a rather unfortunate design of references ... btw, stop moving the accepted answer around, only one can be the accepted one :)

Comment: sorry, I just return it to the first one who answered right :)! sorry and thanks again for you help :)